# How do you sort odd and even array numbers in descending and ascending order?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I need help to sort numbers in an array in ascending and descending order. Even numbers should be ascending and odd numbers descending.

I have managed to sort the number in ascending order but want to do the opposite for the odd numbers.

Actual Results: Both odd and even numbers ascending

[image: results]

Expected Results: Even numbers ascending and odd numbers descending

[image: Results]

```java
System.out.println("\n" + "random numbers generated:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayList).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", ""));
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < arrayList.length; j++) {
        if(arrayList[i] > arrayList[j]) {
            temporaryArray = arrayList[i];
            arrayList[i] = arrayList[j];
            arrayList[j] = temporaryArray;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("\n" + "random numbers arranged:");

int[] arrayTwo = Arrays.copyOf(arrayList, arrayList.length);

for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
    if(arrayTwo[i]%2!=0) {
        System.out.print(arrayTwo[i] + " ");
    }
}

System.out.print("| ");

for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
    if(arrayTwo[i]%2==0) {
        System.out.print(arrayTwo[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

How can I reverse array for odd numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you :

- 1. sort all numbers in ascending order,
- 2. extract the odd numbers to a second array and
- 3. reverse this new array.
     Manipulating two different orderings in a same array would prove much more complicated.
     On a side note, if you don't have a requirement not to, I'd recommend using the `Arrays` library's `Arrays.sort()` to simplify your code. It is very readable and has lower complexity of O(N log N).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is write a recursive function like so:

```
public static void printOddReversed(int[] array, int index) {
    if (index == array.length)
        return;

    printOddReversed(array, index + 1);

    if (array[index] % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.print(array[index] + " ");
    }
}
```

and then instead of the second loop, call it like so:

```
printOddReversed(arrayTwo, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input 

How would I do this without using a method?

Comment: The recursive solution can only be done with a separate function.

Comment: What you can do instead is iterate though arrayTwo from the end to the beginning and print the numbers only if they're odd (since arrayTwo is sorted it would print them in descending order)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that is by using a special comparator:

```
        if (a%2 == 0) {
            if (b%2 == 0) {
                return Integer.compare(a,b);
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            if (b%2 == 0) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return Integer.compare(b, a);
            }
        }
```

UPDATE: Example

```
    int[] arrayList = {959, 321, 658, 3, 506, 165, 560, 582, 199, 533, 178};
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < arrayList.length; j++) {
            if(compare(arrayList[i], arrayList[j]) > 0) {
                int temporaryArray = arrayList[i];
                arrayList[i] = arrayList[j];
                arrayList[j] = temporaryArray;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayList));
```

...

```
private static int compare(int a, int b) {
    if (a%2 == 0) {
        if (b%2 == 0) {
            return Integer.compare(a,b);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        if (b%2 == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return Integer.compare(b, a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by just reversing

```
for (int i = arrayList.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    if(arrayTwo[i]%2==0) {
        System.out.print(arrayTwo[i] + " ");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).